# Large-scale applications using protractor?

Tags: angularjs, testing, integration-testing, protractor

I would like to see source code of large applications (if possible, in production) with e2e tests using protractor.

Could anybody provide links to such apps?

Comment: I've searched into https://builtwith.angularjs.org/ but haven't found something really matching the question. Maybe the protractor team have more info? @jmr

Comment: Do you know such apps/projects @elgalu? (only one user can be notified per comment)

Comment: You really think anyone is going to give you the source code of a project? It's like going to buy a car and ask if you can have it for free.. No way!

Comment: @GuyT I am not the owner of the question (I only opened the bounty) but I was wondering if there were large (angular-based) open-source projects that would be logically tested Protractor for e2e tests. If this is not yet the case, I'm sure it will be one day. I do not see why an open-source web application (and there are a bunch!) would not use protractor in the near future and thus publish their own tests as it is already the case with unit tests.

Comment: @glepretre I get that. But you have to understand that when you talk about 'in production' most people will think that you mean an enterprise application. I agree with you that there will be someday a huge opensource Angular project with your specifications. The OP is asking it in a strange way(in my opinion).

Comment: In my opinion the question is off-topic for this site. It should fall under the `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.` category.

Comment: Also, this question can never result in anything else but an answer with a link to an off-site resource, something that is strongly discouraged on this site.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, finding such source code with associated tests may prove to be difficult.

After doing some searching, this is the closest thing I could find.

http://product.moveline.com/testing-angular-apps-end-to-end-with-protractor.html

Perhaps you would be better off finding the differences between how unit tests and e2e tests using Protractor are performed and go from there?

For unit tests, I have found the [AngularUI/Bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap) source and tests to be an invaluable resource. Good luck!

Comment: This is not really the answer I expected but since you're the only one who gave it a try, here are the +50 ;)